# Message: file_get_contents(sso.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get data from JSON file manually, not from URL. I use function **file_get_contents**. And I got error :

> Message: file_get_contents(sso.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Even though the path is correct. This is my structure project :

```
-> kalenderkerja
   -> application
      -> controllers
         -> agendakerja
            Kalender.php
            sso.json
   -> assets
   -> ...
```

This is my code in function ***user()*** in file **Kalender.php**

```
public function user() {
    $url = 'sso.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $characters = json_decode($data, true);

    echo $characters['name'];
}
```

And I call the controller in browser **localhost/kalenderkerja/agendakerja/kalender/user**
and I got this error :
[image]

Comment: The "current working directory" is that of the index.php. That's where unqualified/relative paths get looked up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change to

```
$url = __DIR__.'/sso.json';
```

This should work. 
You can learn more about magic constants from [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 4):

Use...

```
file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/sso.json')
```

The issue is that because the first file loaded is `/var/www/html/kalenderkerja/index.php`, the *working directory* becomes `/var/www/html/kalenderkerja`. This applies to any included / required files.

Relative file paths in PHP can be tricky so always try to use static prefixes like `__DIR__`, that is...

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned

So in `/var/www/html/kalenderkerja/application/controllers/agendakerja/Kalender.php`, `__DIR__` will be `/var/www/html/kalenderkerja/application/controllers/agendakerja`